# What is the typical way to run parameterized function names coming from a third part library without knowing the names in advance?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In my case, all the different functions in faker.js. From my code, I want to run dynamically different functions depending on input parameters. Is eval the only way? Or should I do some switch mapper? But then I need to keep that up to date with the faker.js library.
thanks in advance.

Comment: `switch` works, as does `instance[methodName]()`. Do not use `eval`.

Comment: ① Is this question dependent on faker.js? Then you probably want to tag it as such. ② Please [edit] the question to provide a [mre] that demonstrates the basic issue (it can be a toy example that shows a few different functions you want to choose between), or else you're going to get vague answers if any, and the question might even be closed as not providing enough details.